# Navbar collides with text

Tags: html, css

So I'm creating a simple blog-like website to record my activities this summer, and I need some help. I've created a dropdown navbar, but it runs into my  tag. I just need to get it to move upwards to another line so it doesn't run into that tag. This is my first post on StackOverflow so I'm not allowed to post pictures, but I can link you to my picture on Imgur. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcfkM.jpg

Here's the HTML for the NavBar

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html" id="selected">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="why.html">About</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="why.html">Why Do It</a></li>
                <li><a href="future.html">Future Plans</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#top">Archive</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#June">June 2015</a></li>
                <li><a href="#July">July 2015</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And here's the CSS for the NavBar

```
/*************************
NAVIGATION
*************************/

/* Strip the ul of padding and list styling */

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Create a horizontal list with spacing */

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

/* Style for menu links */

nav li a {
    display: block;
    min-width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Hover state for top level links */

nav li:hover a {
    background: #888888;
}

/* Style for dropdown links */

nav li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

/* Hover state for dropdown links */

nav li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #888888;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Hide dropdown links until they are needed */

nav li ul {
    display: none;
}

/* Make dropdown links vertical */

nav li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

/* Prevent text wrapping */

nav li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

/* Display the dropdown on hover */

nav ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Please tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: You code seem to work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/gvprsc2v/1/   It's not clear what this issue is.

Comment: The problem was not with the navbar itself, but with the navbar colliding into another element. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the hover style to use absolute positioning, otherwise you'll push aside the later content when you hover over the menu items:

```
nav ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

Also, you should do a `clear` on the element following the `nav`, so it appears on a new line.

Example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rvs5bs23/1/

Comment: Possibly work mentioning that the `li` should be **either** `float` or `inline-block` not *both*

Comment: Thanks Dave R. for the help! It was the clear that I needed to do. I also took your advice and used absolute positioning on the hover style. Also, thank you Paulie_D for the advice on the float/inline-block.

Comment: @SkyyCP You're very welcome. Best of luck with the rest of the project :)